# Asp .net Core создать/заапдейтить базу

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Как в Asp .net Core создать/применить миграцию? `update-database` в VS пишет

> "The EntityFramework package is not installed on project"

Comment: Ну у Вас же черным по белому написано, что в проекте не установлен `Entity Framework`. Добавьте его к проекту через `nuget`, например.

Comment: @Donil, установлен.

Comment: Хм, а студия иначе считает. Попробуйте переустановить его

Comment: @Donil, это Core  проект, а не обычный. Я почти уверенн, что дело в этом.

Comment: Нашел ответ. Все делается через виндовую консоль.
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

Comment: Ответ уже был дан https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715037/asp-net-core-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0