# ASP.NET CORE, не мигрируется база

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Доброе время суток,есть проект, взятый он с оф. сайта :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model

Такой себе туториал и дойдя до Миграции, выводит :

"Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6. "

Хотя EntityFrameworkCore  по сабжу доступен в   ASP.NET CORE. После инсталляции с пакета NuGet Entity выбивает ошибку :

"Исключение при вызове "SetData" с "2" аргументами: "Тип "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAP
roject" сборки "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5
0a3a" не помечен как сериализуемый."
C:\Users\Виталий Заярный.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 знак:20
+     $domain.SetData <<<< ('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)"
, но в других проектах, которые не касается ентити, всё вполне нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityFrameworkCore и доступен, он же Вам пишет, что у Вас установлены и EF Core и EF 6 (типа не знает он в чем миграцию делать), для выполнения миграции на EF 6 используйте в консоли диспетчера пакетов команду EntityFramework\Add-Migration, ну а для EF Core: EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration

Comment: Ах, я понял ошибку свою, я использовал EntityFramework\Add-Migration, а не EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration. как-то даже стыдно.
Благодарю. о.о